# Running the erlang vm inside a process

Tags: erlang

It's possible to run the erlang VM *inside* a process?

I'm asking this because I'm trying to use some code using the erl_nif, witch is very cool indeed, but I have to send information back to the process that could possibily spawn the VM. The only approach I've thinked is to create some IPC communication, like pipes or reading from COUT, but this imposes the need of some protocol, and would be cool if I could call what I need directly from the function response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even don't mention that Erlang VM manage OS threads and has event loop, how do you want it will be stable and predictable when running inside an unpredictable OS process? No, you can't run Erlang VM inside an OS process.

Think about Erlang VM as about operating system:

1. Write all your code in Erlang;
2. Use [NIFs](http://www.erlang.org/doc/tutorial/nif.html)/[Port drivers](http://www.erlang.org/doc/tutorial/c_portdriver.html) only if you really need more speed. But be aware - you're in "kernel mode" now!
3. Use [Ports](http://www.erlang.org/doc/tutorial/c_port.html)/[Erl_interface](http://www.erlang.org/doc/tutorial/erl_interface.html)/[C Nodes](http://www.erlang.org/doc/tutorial/cnode.html) if you have many code written in some other language;

Comment: That was what I thought, but I'll end mixing nifs so I'll be able to use the Qt internall classes and send them via COUT. Not that pretty, but...